# How to push jar to system/framework in aosp developing

Tags: android, jar, android-source

I will add custom jars to system, so i push jars(dex) to system/framework/ and reboot, but it doesn't work in Android 9.0 AOSP. How can do this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, because the system jar will be pre-builded and recorded in the image. The only way is to build it with mk.